# How can WPF objects deriving from Freezable be frozen in XAML?

Tags: wpf, performance, xaml, freezable

Many types in WPF derive from `Freezable`.  It provides immutability to mutable POCO objects and allows for improved performance in certain situations.

So my question is, how can I freeze objects in XAML markup?

(Note that I have posted a [similar but different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799911/) too).

Comment: Does this really improve performance? Is there a way to measure the differences between a WPF app without and with po:Freeze="True" set all over the place?

Comment: @AlexandruDicu it can make a big difference depending upon what your so is doing. To verify, you'd need to get before and after CPU traces and compare them.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To freeze a `Freezable` object declared in markup, you use the `Freeze` attribute defined in XML namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/options`.

In the following example, a `SolidColorBrush` is declared as a page resource and frozen. It is then used to set the background of a button.

```
<Page 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:po="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/options" 
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  mc:Ignorable="po">

  <Page.Resources>
    <!-- This brush is frozen -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush" po:Freeze="True" Color="Red" />
  </Page.Resources>

  <!-- Use the frozen brush -->
  <Button Background="{StaticResource MyBrush}">Click Me</Button>

</Page>
```

Source: [Freezable Objects Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509.aspx)

Comment: Shouldn't the last attribute be `mc:Ignorable="po"`?

Answer (score 14):

Add this to your xaml namespace declarations:

```
xmlns:po="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/options"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="po"
```

then, in your freezable objects, include this attribute

```
po:Freeze="True"
```

Comment: Where does the 'mc' namespace come from?

Comment: Oh, i think i missed that. Fixed it now.