# C# Win RT Metro image data storage and exchange with UI on another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, image, user-interface, microsoft-metro

I am writing Metro application for image sharing (kind of). I have separate project for downloading and handling communication to/from server (running on separate thread). I am now wondering what classes should I use for storing image data. I remeber good old days when there was Image class just for this purpose. But today I can seem to find anything like it. There are classes like BitmapSource and DrawingImage, but those are UI classes and can not/should not be used in non-UI threads. What would you suggest me for storing image data and easily transferin it back to UI thread, so I can use it as ImageSource (preferably).
EDIT: I would like to keep image data in memory, if possible (not save to galery/remove on exit)

EDIT: So far I am using IRandomAccessStream, but I dont like this solution, because you can read only once from it (then reset must be performed). Further more - i am not sure how it behaves when multiple BitmapImage(s) have it set as source..

Comment: I think you're mistaken about those classes not being usable from worker threads.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2394157/103167

Comment: I dont think so. In Metro app I do not have access to System.Windows.Media. Instead BitmapImage is originates from Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging and even has Dispatcher property (which means that it is certainly UI class)

Answer (score 1):

See http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/ - the WriteableBitmap may be the ticket.  Haven't played with it, but the overview seems in the ball park.